# Conditionally use a custom UITableViewCell class or a regular UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have subclassed `UITableViewCell` so that I can customize some of its layout. I didn't create a XIB for it. I have been using custom class by simply defining each static cell's class in Interface Builder. Because they're static cells I didn't need to implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

But now I would like to use that custom cell class only if a certain condition is true, otherwise I want that cell's class to be the default `UITableViewCell` class.

I have reverted the static cell's classes to remove the custom class in Interface Builder. So now I need some way to change each cell's class in code. I believe this will need to be done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but I don't know how to dynamically create a custom cell class and use that cell, otherwise use the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two different reuse identifiers for cells of different type. Set up your condition like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
if (needCustomCell) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomIdentifier"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MyCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"CustomIdentifier"];
    }
    ... // Do configuration specific to your custom cell
} else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlainIdentifier"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"PlainIdentifier"];
    }
    ... // Do configuration specific to your regular cell
}
... // Do configuration common to both kinds of cell
return cell;
```

Comment: This works well. I don't however always use the `Default` (basic) cell style - one is `Value1` (right detail) and two are  a custom cell style that has a `UIButton` inside the `contentView`. This is all set up in storyboard and I created outlets for the buttons. Is there any way to use those cells defined in IB and just change the cell class, instead of having to manually recreate all of that in code? Or is there some other best approach?

Comment: @Joey If you have several cell types, you need some code to make a decision between the types. You can use your prototype cells from the storyboard - if you set them up with appropriate reuse identifiers, you could skip both `if (!cell)` conditionals in the code example above, because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` would never return `nil` for your prototype cells.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose the problem is I wouldn't be able to set the reuse identifier because that's only going to fetch a cell that is of a specific class. Because I want to use the same cell defined in Storyboard but conditionally change its class, I would need two different different reuse identifiers for the same cell and two different classes for the same cell, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Joey You could also define two identically looking prototype cells in the storyboard, wire them up to `IBOutlet`s in different classes, and set each one up with its own reuse identifier.

Answer (score 0):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, create the table view instance you need for each case

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
if (conditionIsTrue) {
    cell = [[MyCustomTableViewCell alloc] init];
}
else {
    // create default table view cell
}
```

or something like that...